# Intellij idea darcula theme font size disabled

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, themes

I have the following situation:

I started to use Intellij Idea as the main ide and I am also using Darcula theme. I like everything about it except the annoying small font and annoying line spacing. However, when I try to change those values like with any other theme, I am not able to do that, because both font size and line spacing fields are disabled.

Do you know how to modify Intellij idea's darcula theme default font size?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Save current theme as Your theme, then you will be able to change font size and other options in code editor.
Also if you want change GUI's fonts mark checkbox "Override default font by" in Appearance section.